# Use istio with aad-pod-identity

Tags: istio, azure-aks

Trying to set up istio in Azure AKS together with aad-pod-identity: https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity

How it works is that our pods requests a token from:
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?resource=https://vault.azure.net
and that call should hit the nmi daemonset from aad-pod-identity but it doesn't work. Instead we get a 404 in reponse from envoy.

We tried using a ServiceEntry but it didn't help:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-12T11:39:26Z
  generation: 1
  name: msi-daemonset-address
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2373004"
  selfLink: /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/default/serviceentries/msi-daemonset-address
  uid: 78c6a605-ce13-11e8-8985-feb9b8b89337
spec:
  addresses:
  - 169.254.169.254
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: http
    number: 80
    protocol: HTTP
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Problem solved, we had to add this to the config:
`hosts:
  - some.domain.no
`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you remembered where you had such a config? I have a similar problem....